# Find comments that are not inside quotes using javascript regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to find all remarks in SQL code, for example:

> select 1 --remark to remove

A simple regex would be:

> /--.+/g

But not if it is inside quotes, for example:

> select 1, '--do not remove code'
>
> select 1, 'hamm --do not remove code'
>
> select 'hamm --do not remove code',1

Comment: I think you'll have to make or use a sql parser for that. It's something that actually understand the sql syntax and decides if its part of the string (or comment) or not.

Comment: Try maching what you don't want and capture what you want to find in a group `'[^']*--[^']*'|(--.+)` See https://regex101.com/r/FNMh55/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might match what you don't want to find and capture in a group what you do want to find using an alternation

```
'[^']*--[^']*'|(--.+)
```

That will match

- `[^']*--[^']*'` Match not `'` 0+ times, then -- and again not ' 0+ times
- `|` or
- `(--.+)` Capture in group 1 matching -- and the rest of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FNMh55/1)

```js
[
  "select 1 --remark to remove",
  "select 1, '--do not remove code'",
  "select 1, 'hamm --do not remove code'",
  "select 'hamm --do not remove code',1",
].forEach(s => {
  let res = s.match(/'[^']*--[^']*'|(--.+)/);
  if (undefined !== res[1]) {
    console.log(res[1]);
  }
});
```